# How can I determine the layering of panes in JavaFX

Tags: nodes, javafx-8, pane

I would like to persist a workspace and then restore it when the user opens the window a second time.

For example I have the following:

```
//Create the workspace there the panes will live
Pane workspace = new Pane();
//Create the layers - assume there is code to allow these to be dragged and moved
Pane layer1 = new Pane();
Pane layer2 = new Pane();
Pane layer3 = new Pane();

workspace.getChildren().addAll(layer1, layer2, layer3);
```

I know I can select which layer is on top by doing the following:

```
layer2.toFront();
```

However what I can't seem to find is the ability to determine which layer is currently on top.

i.e.

```
layer1.setOnToFront(event -> {});
layer1.setOnToBack(event -> {});
```

or even

```
boolean onTop = layer1.isOnTop();
```

Is there a way to determine where a node is so when the workspace is open, the front pane can be made visible again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rendering order (back to front) of nodes in a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html), is based upon the index of the node in the pane's child list.

So you can determine the index of a given node using the following function:

```
int idx = pane.getChildren().indexOf(layerX);
```

You can determine the top node using:

```
Node top = 
    pane.getChildren.size() > 0
        ? pane.getChildren().get(pane.getChildren().size() - 1)
        : null;
```

You can listen for changes in node order using a [ListChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html):

```
pane.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {
    public void onChanged(Change<Item> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            // process the next change.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually - it was simpler than I thought.  Simply creating a node of JSON based on pane.getChildren() exports them in the correct order. So I have no need to know which layer is which.  But your solution would also work.

Answer (score 2):

[`toFront()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront--) moves the node to the front simply by re-ordering the parent's child node list (specifically, it moves the node to the last position in the list).

So you can determine the order simply by looking at `workspace.getChildren()`. If you want to be notified when the order changes, just register a listener with the list:

```
workspace.getChildren().addListener((Change change) -> { });
```